# Export Vagrant VM with all it's synced folders

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vagrant

Let's saying I'm working on a vagrant VM named `foo` and it sits on my host machine at `~/foo`.  In my scenario, foo uses VirtualBox as the provider and is using synced folders to configure and provide important services inside the VM (i.e. MySQL config files).  Everything works just fine, and I can start (provision) and stop the VM.  If it makes a difference, `~/foo` is mounted (in the VM) as `/vagrant`.

Now, I want to essentially "export" the current state of the VM along with all of the synced files.  Is this possible?  I don't need VM snapshots and I don't need the VM to be in a running state (halted is fine / preferred).  Any VirtualBox or Vagrant solution would be appreciated as long as I can import the VM into another computer's VirtualBox environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are using Vagrant with its default shared folder turned on.
So what happens is /vagrant is being mounted on boot. When you shut the machine down, /vagrant will be unmounted. So no data is really saved inside the vm.

What you can do is to use Vagrant [rsync mechanism](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html) instead of Shared Folders.
This way you will actually copy files from host machine to guest machine.

Comment: This is perfect, just what I was looking for!  I was unaware of the Vagrant "rsync mechanism" (though I'm familiar with rsync in general).  I'll need to investigate it further, but after a quick glance at the documentation, I think this will work just fine.